# Sorting tabs in order 1, 8, 28 not 1, 28, 8

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, tabs

I have multiple Excel files, each with different numbering systems.
Those include Item (#ofsheet), so like Item (1), Item (8), Item (28).
Those organize themselves by Item 1, 28, and 8 when it should be 1, 8, 28.

This code puts the items into Item (1), Item (11), Item (2), Item (34) order.

```vb
Sub sortAscendinfg()

    Dim i, N, k As Double

    'Count the number of worksheets and store the number in variable "n"
    N = Application.Sheets.Count
    
    'Do the following look for each worksheet again
    For i = 1 To N
    
        'Loop through all worksheets until the second last one (later you use the .move after function)
        For k = 1 To N - 1
            'If the name is larger than the following worksheet, change the sequence of these two worksheets.
            'In order to enable a proper comparison, change all characters to lower case (UCase = Upper case works
            'the same way.
            If LCase(Sheets(k).Name) > LCase(Sheets(k + 1).Name) Then Sheets(k).Move After:=Sheets(k + 1)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to show the code you're working with, and explain the exact error you're getting when you try to modify it.  It looks like you're comparing the sheet names as text, when you need to sort them as numbers, but without your code it's difficult to make any suggestions for how to fix it.

Comment: You do realize that your sheets are being sorted correctly (the first digit is the first difference: `1, 2, 8`) and that you prefer a different kind of sorting. Please, share the code which you used to get the undesired results, so we can build on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sort Incrementing Sheets

- The `SortIncrementingSheetsTEST` procedure is an example of how to use (call) the main `SortIncrementingSheets` procedure.
- The main `SortIncrementingSheets` procedure needs the `GetLastInteger` procedure to work.
- The `GetLastInteger` procedure returns the last integer (the last consecutive digits as a number) found in a string.
- The `GetLastIntegerTEST` procedure is an example of how to use (call) the `GetLastInteger` procedure. It prints `13` in the Immediate window since `13` is the last integer in the example string `Sheet1(013)`.
- Basically, all the sheet names and their corresponding last integers are written to the `Keys` and `Items` of a `dictionary`, which is then utilized when sorting the sheets. Uncomment the `Debug.Print` lines to better understand how the procedure works by reviewing the results in the Immediate window.
- The sort in the procedure is based on the following Microsoft Docs article by [`MVP Tom Urtis`](https://www.atlaspm.com/):
  [`Sort Worksheets Alphanumerically by Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/sort-worksheets-alphanumerically-by-name)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SortIncrementingSheetsTEST()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    SortIncrementingSheets wb
End Sub

Sub SortIncrementingSheets( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook)
' Needs 'GetLastInteger'.
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sh As Object
    
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        dict.Add sh.Name, GetLastInteger(sh.Name)
    Next sh
    'Debug.Print Join(dict.Keys, ",")
    'Debug.Print Join(dict.Items, ",")
    
    Dim shCount As Long: shCount = wb.Sheets.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    For i = 1 To shCount - 1
        For j = i + 1 To shCount
            If dict(wb.Sheets(j).Name) < dict(wb.Sheets(i).Name) Then
                wb.Sheets(j).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(i)
                'Debug.Print "Moved '" & wb.Sheets(i).Name & "' from '" _
                    & j & " to " & i & "'."
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Sheets sorted.", vbInformation

End Sub

Function GetLastInteger( _
    ByVal SearchString As String) _
As Long
    
    Dim nLen As Long: nLen = Len(SearchString)
    
    Dim DigitString As String
    Dim CurrentChar As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FoundDigit As Boolean
    
    For n = nLen To 1 Step -1
        CurrentChar = Mid(SearchString, n, 1)
        If CurrentChar Like "#" Then ' it's a digit
            DigitString = CurrentChar & DigitString
            If Not FoundDigit Then
                FoundDigit = True
            End If
        Else ' it's not a digit
            If FoundDigit Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next n
    
    If FoundDigit Then
        GetLastInteger = CLng(DigitString)
    Else
        GetLastInteger = -1
    End If

End Function

Sub GetLastIntegerTEST()
    Debug.Print GetLastInteger("Sheet1(013)")
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great for my sheets, thank you!  Follow-up, how would I edit it to work for the other way I have tabs organized?  I have a different worksheet with tabs labeled Item# number, so for example they are PS# 124, PS# 225, PS# 34.

Comment: You're welcome. It is the same code for your new example. It just looks at the last occurring consecutive digits (resulting in 34. 124, 225). It doesn't 'concern itself' with the text part. If you have sheets that don't have numbers (`- 1`), they will be moved to the beginning of the workbook.

Answer (score 1):

This may be able to be done better and without seeing your code, I have no idea where you're going wrong but I suggest as a string, if you're treating it that way, 8 is greater than 28.

You can test this by going into the immediate window in the VBA editor and entering and hitting enter ...

```
?str(8) > str(28)
```

... the result is true.  Not what you want.

Try this, it worked for me.

There are a couple of caveats though, there can be no other opening or closing brackets in the name of the worksheet other than those you have at the end as you've specified, e.g. "**Item (28)**" ... this won't be ok, "**Item (other brackets) (28)**"

```
Public Sub SortSheets()
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet, objSubSheet as Worksheet
    Dim lngSortOrder As Long, lngSortSubOrder As Long
    
    For Each objSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lngSortOrder = Replace(Split(objSheet.Name, "(")(1), ")", "")
        
        For Each objSubSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            lngSortSubOrder = Replace(Split(objSubSheet.Name, "(")(1), ")", "")
            
            If lngSortOrder < lngSortSubOrder Then
                objSheet.Move Before:=Sheets(objSubSheet.Index)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - this didn't work for me, but I know you posted it before I posted my code.  I appreciate you taking the time to post. :)